# How to mark a read mail as Unread in IMAP using objective c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, imap

I am trying to mark a read mail as Unread on click of UNREAD button.**The mail is marked as unread but on logging in again that mail is shown as read**.This is the part of the code that i am using :-

```
-(IBAction)markAsUnreadButtonAction:(id)sender{
    actionFlag = MailActionUnread;
    if(imapMessage){
        [[imapMessage flags] remove:PantomimeSeen];
        [mailListTable deselectAll:nil];
        [self setEmptyFieldsOnMailWindow];
        [currentImapFolder setFlags:[imapMessage flags] messages:[NSArray arrayWithObject:imapMessage]];
        int selectedRow = [mailListTable selectedRow];
        NSLog(@"");
        if(selectedRow >= 0){
            NSMutableDictionary *tempDic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[mailListArray objectAtIndex:selectedRow]];
            [tempDic setObject:@"0" forKey:@"seen"];
            [mailListArray replaceObjectAtIndex:selectedRow withObject:tempDic];
            [tempDic release];
            [mailListTable reloadData];
            [unreadMailsCountDict setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[[imapStore selectedFolder] numberOfUnreadMessages]] forKey:[[imapStore selectedFolder] name]];
            [totalMailsCountDict setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[[imapStore selectedFolder] numberOfUnreadMessages]] forKey:[[imapStore selectedFolder] name]];
            [mailBoxesListTable reloadData];
        }
    }

}
```

Please advise what should be done to show the Unread mail as unread on logging in again.